# Greatest-n-per-group query including rows that don't have 'n'

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I know that this is a common question but I haven't been able to find an answer to this specific problem:

I have two tables:

```
+--------------+     +-------------------------------+
| temp1        |     | temp2                         |
+----+---------+     +----+----+---------------------+
| id | name    |     | id | fk | ts                  |
+----+---------+     +----+--------------------------+
| 1  | first   |     | 1  | 1  | 2020-06-19 23:56:46 | 
| 2  | second  |     | 2  | 1  | 2020-06-19 22:56:46 | 
| 3  | third   |     | 3  | 2  | 2020-06-19 21:56:46 | 
+----+---------+     | 4  | 2  | 2020-06-19 20:56:46 | 
                     +----+--------------------------+
```

In order to get for each entry in temp1 the corresponding entry from temp2 with the newest timestamp I am running the following query:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id AS id,
    t1.name AS name,
    t2.ts AS ts
FROM
    (temp2 t2
    JOIN temp1 t1)
WHERE
    t2.ts = (SELECT MAX(t3.ts)
        FROM
            temp2 t3
        WHERE
            t2.fk = t3.fk)
        AND t2.fk = t1.id
```

This results in:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   | ts                  |
+----+------------------------------+
| 1  | first  | 2020-06-19 23:56:46 | 
| 2  | second | 2020-06-19 21:56:46 | 
+----+------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to alter this query in order to include the rows from temp1 that do not have a corresponding value in temp2?

The desired result would be:

```
+----+--------+---------------------+
| id | name   | ts                  |
+----+------------------------------+
| 1  | first  | 2020-06-19 23:56:46 | 
| 2  | second | 2020-06-19 21:56:46 | 
| 3  | third  | NULL                | 
+----+------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.ts
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT t2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t2.fk ORDER BY t2.ts DESC) as seqnum
      FROM temp2 t2
     ) t2
     ON t2.fk = t1.id AND seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with a correlated subquery in the `SELECT` list:

```
SELECT t1.*,
  (SELECT MAX(t2.ts) FROM temp2 t2 WHERE t2.fk = t1.id) ts
FROM temp1 t1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k8FDytrDdCd3Qc2kZ66DS7/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name   | ts                  |
| --- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 1   | first  | 2020-06-19 23:56:46 |
| 2   | second | 2020-06-19 21:56:46 |
| 3   | third  |                     |
```